# Angular ng-pattern Crashes Browser

Tags: angularjs

We have a regular expression that we use for e-mail. Our application is inheriting the regular expression, so it may not be an option to switch it... Anyway, the same set of steps seem to crash the javascript in the browser. I've been able to reproduce in IE and Chrome, but not Firefox. Here is the code:

```
var mod = angular.module("myApp", []);

mod.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    //Pattern that blows up the browser during ng-pattern
    $scope.emailPattern = /^(?!.*\.{2})([a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+([\.][a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*)@((([\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]){2,}[\.])*(([a-zA-Z0-9][\-]?){1,})+).(([\.]([a-zA-Z0-9][\-]?){2,}([a-zA-Z0-9])*)+)$/;


});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="emailForm" novalidate>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" name="email" maxlength="80" required ng-pattern="emailPattern">
    </form>
    <br>
    {{user.email}}
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z745w/1/). Here are the basic steps that will cause the browser to crash:

1. Type a bunch of alpha characters into the text box until it is full (other inputs may work, but this is what I've used).
2. Backspace 2 characters.
3. Hit the **Home** key to return to the front of the input.
4. Type the characters: **a@**

This will crash IE and Chrome consistently. Has anybody encountered this bug before? Any known workarounds?

Comment: I was able to reproduce.

Comment: Hey I notice on the docs for ng-pattern it says: '* @param {string=} ngPattern Sets `pattern` validation error key if the value does not match the
 *    RegExp pattern expression. Expected value is `/regexp/` for inline patterns or `regexp` for
 *    patterns defined as scope expressions.'.
Maybe your problem is with using scope expression and the inline patterns.

Comment: Crash exists when I use it as a scope expression or inline expression. Making the regular expression "simpler" won't crash the browser, but there should be nothing wrong with validating the regex as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is with the regex expression itself.

If you went to any regex validator site (like  http://regexpal.com/), using the original expression, the same problem would occur there (with the browser freezing).

---

Change:

```
$scope.emailPattern = /^(?!.*\.{2})([a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+([\.][a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*)@((([\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]){2,}[\.])*(([a-zA-Z0-9][\-]?){1,})+).(([\.]([a-zA-Z0-9][\-]?){2,}([a-zA-Z0-9])*)+)$/;
```

To:

```
$scope.emailPattern = /^(?!.*\.{2})([a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+([\.][a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*)@((([\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]){2,}[\.])*(([a-zA-Z0-9][\-]?))+).(([\.]([a-zA-Z0-9][\-]?){2,}([a-zA-Z0-9])*)+)$/;
```

Comment: Good set of eyes on that unnecessary quantifier that was causing excessive backtracking.